# LocalHost/GS does not display sencha default app

Tags: extjs

i want to learn sencha touch2.for that i downloaded SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3.and sencha-touch-2.0.1.1-commercial.and i give sencha and sencha generate app GS ../GS command.it work fine.then give one more command as given in DOCS http:/localhost/GS/.but it gives error.it does not display default sencha app.please tell me what i did wrong.please help me.